# Does the concept of a map service exist in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, map-service, feature-service, terminology

I'm new to web GIS.

I have created an ArcGIS Online account that contains:

- Web Maps
- Feature Layers (hosted)

---

It is my guess that the term *feature layer* is a synonym for *feature service*.

If that's correct, then in addition to creating *feature services* in ArcGIS Online, is it also possible to create *map services* in ArcGIS Online?

- The purpose of the *map service* would be to query the data in the layers via HTTP.

---

*(I suspect I've misunderstood something here. I'm finding the web GIS terminology/concepts to be difficult to parse.)*

Comment: The way I would describe it is as follows:                Feature Layer and Feature Service are not interchangeable as words (ie: Are not synonums), however a Feature Layer has an associated FeatureService . ( I do find ESRI's naming conventions to be terribly confusing..

Comment: Yes there was, you were too quick before I was able to correct it!

Comment: If the goal is to query the data in the layers via HTTP, then you can use hosted feature layers for that.  Is there any specific other reason why you want to achieve it specifically using "map services"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can publish map services to ArcGIS Online although your maps can consume ones you've published to a Portal environment.  You can query your data from the feature service you already have (the hosted feature layer).  Both map and feature services support querying, but feature services add extra functionality like editing.

See the ESRI support doco on the [query](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm) end point for help formulating your query.